# Java Regex not matching?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have this code, but it does not seem to be working.

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("IMGURSESSION=([0-9a-zA-Z]*);");
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher("IMGURSESSION=blahblah; path=/; domain=.imgur.com");
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

Would anyone know why?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the regex itself. It worked when I tested it with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/).

Comment: I know that. I know regex enough to know it will work. And RegexBuddy--40 dollars! Insane! I just stick to http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Matcher#matches()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) method attempts to match the **entire input sequence** against the pattern.

```
Pattern.compile("IMGURSESSION=([0-9a-zA-Z]*);.*$"); //true
Pattern.compile("IMGURSESSION=([0-9a-zA-Z]*);"); //false
```

Answer (score 2):

the matches Method match against the entire input string.

if you will match only a subsequence you can use the find() method.

the 3 different ways to match with a matcher are explained in the java docs:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your aim is to extract the `IMGURSESSION`:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("IMGURSESSION=([0-9a-zA-Z]*);.*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("IMGURSESSION=blahblah; path=/; domain=.imgur.com");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Just make sure you put in a match all pattern at the end to satisfy the "matcher" semantics.